# setup for R optimization problem with weights constraints

Tags: r, optimization

Looking for help in setting up below optimization in R.   Trying to understand which optimization package is best.  I don't have much code available yet and am looking for ideas on best tools/packages to even start setting the problem up, thank you.

```
scores<-c(1.7, 3.0, 5.3, 7.0, 8.43, 6.8, 6.8)
target_scores<-c(2,3,6,7,8.5,7,7)
weights<-rep(0,7)
```

objective function:

```
objective<-function(weights){

                  weights_pct<-weights/sum(weights)

                  return((sum(scores*weights_pct)-1.05)+sum(abs(scores*weights_pct - target_scores)))            
                }
```

The optimization goal is to return the optimal set of weights.
I've tried to include the fact that weights should sum to 1 directly in the objective function.  If there
is an alternate way to do this, open to changes/enhancements in problem setup.
Advice on best solver to use for this problem welcome(have looked at optim and solve.qp so far).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `CVXR` would be a powerful tool for your problem

```
library(CVXR)
scores<-c(1.7, 3.0, 5.3, 7.0, 8.43, 6.8, 6.8)
target_scores<-c(2,3,6,7,8.5,7,7)

# declare variable
weights<-Variable(length(scores))

# set up minimization problem and solve it
constraints <- list(weights >=0,sum(weights) == 1) # the constraint for sum up to 1 with positive weights
f <- Minimize((sum(scores*weights)-1.05)+sum(abs(scores*weights - target_scores)))
problem <- Problem(f,constraints)
result <- solve(problem)

# show results of `weights`
> result$getValue(weights)
           [,1]
[1,] 0.02049869
[2,] 0.10787489
[3,] 0.14437726
[4,] 0.17562971
[5,] 0.20452523
[6,] 0.17354711
[7,] 0.17354711
```